# SASS - Passing variable to @each loop

Tags: variables, sass

I'm using npm module '[iconfont](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-iconfont)' to manage my theme's icons (with gulp).
The module use a template to generate SCSS files. See below :

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: '<%= fontName %>';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url('../<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.eot');
    src: url('../<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../<%= fontPath %><%= fontName %>.svg#<%= fontName %>') format('svg');

}

.<%= className %>[class^="<%= className %>-"],
.<%= className %>[class*=" <%= className %>-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: '<%= fontName %>';
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none;
}

$icons: (
    <%= glyphs.map(function(glyph) {
        return glyph.name + ': \'' + '\\' + glyph.unicode[0].charCodeAt(0).toString(16).toUpperCase() + '\''
    }).join(',\n    ') %>
);

@each $name, $icon in $icons {
    .<%= className %>-#{$name}:##Dynamic position### {
        font-family: '<%= fontName %>';
        content: $icon;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it uses a '@each' loop to generate my icons class.

I've created a mixin to use it. see below :

```
@mixin svgicon($name, $fontsize, $lineheight, $color, $position){
    @extend .icon;
    @extend .icon-#{$name}:#{$position};
    @extend #{$position};
    font-size:$fontsize;
    line-height:$lineheight;
    color:$color;
}
```

Here is my problem : by default, the icon module generate the icon on an ::before pseudo-element, and i would like to be able to choose the pseudo-element in my mixin parameters.

Any idea ?

Thx

Comment: There's nothing to pass.  The selectors are generated long before you call your mixin.  There's nothing *to* do, other than modify the `@each` block.

Comment: By modifying the `@each` block, do you mean create a second selector with the ::after pseudo element, and create a second mixin too ?

Comment: You would need to create another selector in the `@each`.  The mixin would just need to be modified to extend the correct selector.  Most people don't want to modify 3rd party libraries to suit their purposes.

Comment: Ok i got it. But i manage it in other way. I've remove the :before in th `@each` bloc, and made a condition in my mixin, based on my parameter

Answer (score 0):

Solution (much simple i think)

I've removed de :before from `@each` block, then modified my mixin this way :

```
@mixin svgicon($name, $fontsize, $lineheight, $color, $position:before){

    @if $position == 'before'{

        &:before{

            @extend .icon;
            @extend .icon-#{$name};
            font-size:$fontsize;
            line-height:$lineheight;
            color:$color;

        }

    } @else {

        &:after{

            @extend .icon;
            @extend .icon-#{$name};
            font-size:$fontsize;
            line-height:$lineheight;
            color:$color;

        }

    }

}
```

Now i only have to include my mixin this way :

```
@include svgicon('gyro', 10px, 10px, red, 'before');
```